# ListSubItems - Method or Data Member not found

Tags: vba, vb6

I am getting the error "Method or Data Member not found" for ListSubItems whenever I try to compile the project. I have added the SP6 component, MSCOMCTL.OCX. But still I am getting this error.

```
Public Function SetBoldToListItemInListView(lv As ListView, lvwItem As ListItem, bBold As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error GoTo EH

    ResetBoldInListView Not bBold, lv  
    lvwItem.EnsureVisible

    For i = 1 To lvwItem.ListSubItems.Count
        lvwItem.ListSubItems(i).Bold = True
    Next  

    lvwItem.Bold = True 
    lvwItem.Selected = True 
    lv.Refresh  
    SetBoldToListItemInListView = True

ExitProc:
    On Error Resume Next  
    Exit Function

EH:    
    Error_Handler "Support / CheckUncheckItemsInListView"
    Resume ExitProc
End Function
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me.  I would verify your references/components.

Comment: Components :

Desaware SpyWorks 6 Hook Control, 
Microsoft Calendar Control 2007, 
Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0(SP6), 
Microsoft FlexGrid Control 6.0(SP6), 
Microsoft Hierarchical FlexGrid Control 6.0(SP4) (OLEDB), 
Microsoft Masked Edit Control 6.0(SP3), 
Microsoft Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0(SP6), 
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0(SP2), 
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0(SP6), 
Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0(SP6),

Comment: References : 

Visual Basic For Applications, 
Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures, 
Visual Basic objects and procedures, 
Microsoft scripting runtime, 
MIcrosoft Data Formatting Object Library 6.0(SP6), 
OLE Automation, 
Microsoft Data Binding Collection VB 6.0 (SP4), 
Windows API (ANSI), 
Microsoft ActiveX data Objects 6.0 BackCompact Library,

Comment: It's probably the references, order in that list matters.  Also, when you're typing the code and auto-suggest pops-up, the order of the libraries for duplicate objects (like ListItem) will depend on that order.  You could try hard-coding the one you want, i.e. `lvwItem as VBA.ListItem` or simply re-type it in the declaration and select the second (or third) instance of ListItem

Comment: I checked in Object browser. I have COMCTLLIB and MSCOMCTLLIB ListItems. In MSCOMCTLLIB listitems class is having ListSubitems as member. But it is not there in COMCTLLIB. My project is taking ListItems class from COMCTLLIB. How can i change it to MSCOMCTLLIB as default?

Comment: You don't need Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 if you have  Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone still looking for an answer you need to add a component `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)`.

Go to `Projects -> Components (Ctrl+ T)` and check the checkbox for it.

[image: Project -> Components]

[image: Add Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)]

Once this is added, you will also see extra components in the available GUI elements.

[image: New components]